# C++11: lambda, currying

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, variadic-templates, currying

I have the following code. Can you explain to me how it works?

```
template<typename Function, typename... Arguments>
auto curry(Function func, Arguments... args) {
    return [=](auto... rest) {
        return func(args..., rest...);
    };
}

int main() {
    auto add = [](auto x, auto y) {
        return x + y;
    };
    auto add4 = curry(add, 4);
    std::cout << add4(3) << '\n'; //output: 7. (Ok)

}
```

Comment: Do you have any specifics on what you do not understand?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, you have to know what [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) is, or in your question, this is specifically a case of [**partial application**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) (to which currying is related, but slightly different).

Basically, it means **reducing** a function with a certain number of parameters to create *another function* with some of the parameter's values fixed.

I your exampled, the original function is `add(x,y)` which has two parameters *x* and *y*. You *reduce* the function's arity add by setting *x* to 4 and create the reduced function `add4(y)` such as

*add4(y) = add(x,y)* where *x = 4*

Now how is this achieved in your c++ code ? With the help of **variadic templates**, **variadic functions** and  **lambda functions**.

[Lambda functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11#7627218) are in c++ since C++11. In essence they are anonymous function created on the fly, which can be stored in a variable. You create `add` as a lambda in `main()` :

```
auto add = [](auto x, auto y) {
 return x + y;
};
```

One recognizes the lambda by the pattern `[] (list-of-arguments) {function-body};`

Note : the `[]` is not always empty, see "capturing variables" [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11#7627218), we'll get back to it later.

Now the curry function's purpose is to take one of these lambdas functions `func` and a certain number of values as arguments, and define a **new function** by **assigning** the values, in order, to the first arguments of `func`.

The "*certain number of arguments*" mechanism is permitted by the [variadic template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template#C.2B.2B) argument `Arguments... args` which permits to call the template with any number of types as template parameters (as long as they are known as compile time). So in our case, the passed argument is 4, so `Arguments... args` will be replaced by `int`, and the instance of `curry` will accept as parameters a lambda and an `int`.

If we look at the code of `curry`, we see that it is only a lambda function itself, (it is a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function), just like `printf()`) whose only purpose is to concatenate the arguments whose value is already fixed when instantiating the template(`args...`) and those whose value is passed as arguments to the curried function(`rest...`).

The [=] sign is a special *capture* for lambda function which allows to use all local variables in the function body (here it allows to use `args`).

So to wrap it up, here's what happening in your main function :

1. You create a variable named `add` which contains a *lambda
   function*, taking two arguments and adding them.
2. When you call `curry(add,4)` you instantiate the `curry` template.

   - The first template parameter `Function` is the type of `add` (a lambda taking two `int` and returning an `int`)
   - The second variadic parameters contains only one type : the type of  `4`, i.e. `int`

The instantiated `curry` function looks like this

```
curry( (int,int)->(int) func, int arg){
    return [=](auto... rest) {return func(arg, rest...);};
}
```

Note that you never see these types because of `auto` and template type deduction.

3. You then call this instance with `func` = `add` and `arg` = 4
4. You store the result of this instantiation in `add4` which is now a lambda taking one parameter. You can then call `add4` with 3 as argument (`rest...` is 3), which will then call `add(4,3)` and return 7.

Note that technically you could try to call `add4` with more than one argument, since the curried function is a variadic function. The compiler will only fail when it figures out it doesn't have a place for these extra arguments when calling `add` (see it [here](http://ideone.com/rFvvg0))

Comment: Note that the OP's code is not currying, but rather partial application.  Many people are confused between the two.  Currying refers to taking a function of N arguments, and turning it into a chain of N functions of 1 argument.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In my case, this partial application.

Comment: @Louen `auto add = [](auto x, auto y) { return x + y; };` sadly is not possible in _C++11_ since can't use auto in lambda input, this works in _C++14_

Comment: @Moia this is very true, although the question was tagged as c++11 it is actually written in c++14